# Dereference c structure pointer to enable dot notation

Tags: c, syntax, structure

Bit of a silly question, but I can't get this to work. I want to use dot notation to access member variables of a structure, to keep some sprawling code as neat to my eye as possible. I hope I don't get told off for not wanting to do it the traditional way. I'm trying to do this:
    typedef struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } mystruct;

```
mystruct myStArray[5];

void doit (mystruct *i) {
// I want to do this:
    i.a++;
    i.b++;
// rather than this:
    i->a++;
    i->b++;
// or this
    (*i).a++;
    (*i).b++;
}

main () {
    int x;
    for (x=0;x<5;x++) {
        doit(&myStArray[x]);
    }
}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
void doit (mystruct *u) {
  mystruct i = *u;
```

But that dosent work. I know its simple and I used to know how to but I am rusty and just can't remember / find out how to.

Comment: You *could* go for `#define i (*u)`, but I would not let that pass code review.

Comment: Please do not try to change the syntax of C. C syntax uses `->` for access to fields of pointers to structures and so should you.

Comment: Magnus, that answer is the best, but I can't select it as its a comment. I take both you guys points about code review and syntax, but this is for a bit of code only I will see, which is to be further reworked as assembler, so keeping it standard is not a concern of mine. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only options to access a struct member via pointer are `i->a` and `(*i).a`.

In C++ you could write `mystruct &i = *u;`, however that is not valid in C.

You could make a copy of the struct:

```
mystruct j = *u;
j.a++;
```

and copy it back if needed:

```
*u = j;
```

Comment: Unwind and you are right, I am thinking of c++ refs. Joops idea I am already doing in other places, but just in this bit of code I am looking to prune the text a bit so not suitable here. Matt and Unwinds answers are equal I think so I had to choose one. Magnuses comment above is the best answer but he put it in a comment so I can't nominate it as answer. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
mystruct i = *u;
```

will compile and run, but of course it won't affect the data that was in the `mystruct` instance that was passed to `doit()`. It will operate in a local copy, which will be thrown away when the function exits.

There is no way to do what you want, you really should just use the `->` notation.

Perhaps you're thinking of C++'s references?

Answer (score 1):

There is a third way to "dereference" the array: `indexing`

```
 for(i=0; i < cnt; i++ ) {
    myarray[i].a = 42;
    ...
    }
```